# Is there a way to trim leading characters using String.Format()?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Need to know of there is a way to use String.Format to remove leading characters from a string.  I have a limitation in some existing code that I can only pass in a string and a format string for it.

So can you do something like

```
String.Format("Test output: {0:#}","001")
```

and produce the output

> "Test output: 1"

I think the answer is 'No' but I wanted to make sure.

EDIT: To clarify, the format string will be put in a configuration file and the string to be formatted is a value coming out of a database. I can't execute any code on it.  Has to be through the format string.

Comment: You could TrimStart("0") the parameter

Comment: Trimming leading zeroes from a _string_ is not a normal function, so No it is not supported. And the `#` formatting is for numbers too.

Comment: No, I don't think there's any way to accomplish this using that particular overload of `String.Format` alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it on the arg you are passing

```
String.Format("Test output: {0:#}", "001".TrimStart('0'))
```

Alternatively you could probably do a find with replace using a regular expression on the resulting string.

---

An other alternative is to define and pass in your own formatter using a custom implementation of `IFormatProvider`. I am not sure if this is allowed or not based your your last edit.

---

However, based on the restrictions listed, there is no way to do it with just the format string input

Comment: it's not supports the case where the number is 0.5. The output will be ".5"

Comment: @KernelMode - whats wrong with that? `0.5` has by definition 1 leading 0 and `.5` is still a valid value. There was nothing in the language of the question that specified that decimals (fractionals) should retain at least 1 leading 0.

Comment: @Igor Unfortunately, I can't do the TrimStart.  Otherwise, your answer would work fine. Not sure what KernelMode is talking about

Comment: @Kevin - what about a custom format provider that you pass as an arg to `string.Format`?

Comment: @Igor nope.  Don't really have access to the code.  Only able to provide a format string

Comment: @Kevin - too bad. In that case your inkling was right, not much you can do.